# "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length" in nodejs crypto package

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

The value of the data input is encoded with a AES-128 mechanism, where the first 16 characters is the client_secret of my application, which serves as a key to the decoding process.I tried to decode it,it not work.
The code I tried
`

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var app=express();
var crypto=require('crypto');
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    var app_secret_key="my secret key";
    var abc=JSON.stringify(req.body.data);
    var key_app_secret_key=app_secret_key.substring(0,16);
    function decrypt(key,data){
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-cbc',key);
        var decrypted = decipher.update(data,'binary', 'utf8');
        decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
        return decrypted;
    }
    console.log(decrypt(key_app_secret_key,abc));
 });
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('Server running in port 3000');
})
```

`
The error I am getting attach below. Please advise me how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
    at Decipher.final (crypto.js:183:26)
    at decrypt (c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\encryptPract\app.js:18:25)
    at app.post (c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\encryptPract\app.js:22:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (c:\xampp\htdocs\cameacoins\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: First of all AES is not an encoding algorithm, it is an encryption algorithm. You should definitely write your encryption code, too.

Comment: Hi kelalaka, the response is coming from an api, according to there documentation "The value of the data input is encoded with a AES-128 mechanism", what do you think? Still I need to encrypt?

Comment: Which mode of operation, which padding scheme, which output encoding one need to know. If CBC used then the number of blocks must be at least one bigger then the number of plaintext blocks.

Comment: Kelalaka, I can't say that much details but here some information from the documentation,I hope It will help you to understand details Mode of operation is post,padding scheme AES 16 bytes (128 bits).Thank you

Comment: Can you encrypt some with the api? If so, encrypt one block and see the result. If the output 16 bytes, it must be ECB, if 32 bytes it must be CBC. They may use some encoding like base64 that you can see it with the char '=' at the end.

Comment: kelalaka, the last block has no char '=' at the end, Here is the last block 'V5cNRCmn0pfhGzKCIS0OcNcq6WlSXmUPluqY', according to your previous message it's CBC.

Comment: Then try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922462/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-iv-decryption-in-nodejs-encrypted-in-java)

Comment: Thanks kelalaka,Thank you so much, in the documentation they wrote a sample code about decoding. Do you have time to check this? https://github.com/santunu23/apiphp/blob/master/converted.php

Comment: As we can see they use base64 encoding see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538021/why-do-we-use-base64).They convert _ and - to + and / then you have to. After this decode the base 64. Then the first 16 byte's are IV bytes and the rest is the ciphertext.

Comment: I've uses online base64 tool. Yes, the block is [base64](https://www.base64decode.org/)

Comment: Hi kelalaka, Thank you so much for your feedback, I worked as per your advice,but unfortunately failed to get the work done. Do you have a few minutes to look at my code?It's so that you can advice what point I missed. The link is given below.

https://github.com/santunu23/apiphp/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Last two lines should be;  mykey.update(payload,'base64'); 
   var mystr =mykey.final();   // update enables to add as many data as possible. final calculates. If still not working let me know.